# A vector space of linear transformations that cannot be spanned by $8$ elements.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a set of matrices all of which represent linear transformation from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$. All linearly independent subsets of $S$ with $8$ elements will not span $S$. What is $S$?

Comment: $S$ is the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices, which is a vector space in a very natural way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As egreg already pointed out, a linear transformation $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ is a vector space homomorphism and every linear mapping can be represented by a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Thus there is a bijection between them. How many generators has the vector space of $3 \times 3$-matrices? It is generated over $\Bbb R$ by the elementary matrices $(a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 3}$ with $a_{ij} = 1$ for exactly one $i$ and $j$, for example

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
is one generator. How many are there? Exactly $9$. So this is a $9$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ and therefore $8$ elements will not span the whole space, so this is our $S$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of solutions to this puzzle. Either you find a subspace of the space of all such linear transformations that has too high a dimension to be generated by $8$ elements (hint: the whole space has dimension$~9$), or you find another obstruction to a set$~S$ being spanned by $8$ of its elements. For the second type of solution: one possible obstruction is that $S$ is not spanned by anything, because it is not a subspace; another type of obstruction is that you cannot find $8$ elements of$~S$ to begin with. The empty set would be a good candidate for the latter.

Conclusion: from the given information you cannot tell what $S$ is.